# How do I plot a single point on a world map, using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

on a world map, how do I plot a single point?

```
all_states <- map_data("usa")
p <- p + geom_polygon( data=all_states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group, legend = FALSE))
p
```

Also, is it possible to remove the grid and the lat long values form the map?

Comment: Please provide all the code, including libraries, you used to generate the error or sticking point.  Also please include code in code tags using {code} or indenting every line of your code 4 spaces.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
world<-map_data('world')
sf<-data.frame(long=-122.26,lat=37.47)
p <- ggplot(legend=FALSE) +
geom_polygon( data=world, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) +
opts(panel.background = theme_blank()) +
opts(panel.grid.major = theme_blank()) +
opts(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
opts(axis.text.x = theme_blank(),axis.text.y = theme_blank()) +
opts(axis.ticks = theme_blank()) +
xlab("") + ylab("")
# add a single point

p <- p + geom_point(data=sf,aes(long,lat),colour="green",size=4)
p
```

**Note**: Since version 0.9.2 `opts` has been [replaced](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html) by `theme`. So for example, `opts(panel.background = theme_blank())` would become `theme(panel.background = element_blank())`.

Comment: nice, although (1) I like breaking long lines up so they be seen without scrolling horizontally and (2) it's probably best not to call the plot `plot` (the same as the name of the base-R plotting function)

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker I changed plot to p.

Comment: Looks nice.  There's one more "gotcha" here, though, which is that the `+` signs have to be at the *ends* of the split lines rather than the beginning of the continuation lines, unless you parenthesize the whole expression -- otherwise R will think the expression is complete ...

Comment: This plots a filled grey map. If you want just the outlines, use `geom_path()`

Comment: Any ideas how to just plot the continent boundaries?

Comment: I retrieved continent boundaries without country borders like this: `world <- fortify(as.data.frame(map('world', plot=FALSE, interior=FALSE)[c("x","y")])); names(world) <- c("long","lat")`. I'm sure there's an easier way...