# Plotting points converted to grids on map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am new to R. I have a set of lat,lon coordinates and I have generated a map with those points on it.
[image]

**EDIT**: Here is the data for the points,

```
lat <- c(44.3672, 39.3421, 33.978, 36.3901, 32.8388, 38.7519, +
         37.1863, 28.2408, 41.7098, 30.4127)
lon <- c(-83.5215, -86.0034, -84.579, -83.8163, -83.6077, -85.4381,+
         -85.2338, -82.7283, -85.0308, -88.4076)
df <- data.frame(lon, lat)
```

This is the code I used to plot the points, (obtained from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9422167/how-do-i-plot-a-single-point-on-a-world-map-using-ggplot2) post)

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
us_states<-map_data('state')
p <- ggplot(legend=FALSE) +
  geom_polygon( data=us_states, aes(x=long, y=lat,group=group)) +
  theme(panel.background = theme_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = theme_blank()) +
  theme(panel.grid.minor = theme_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text.x = theme_blank(),axis.text.y = theme_blank()) +
  theme(axis.ticks = theme_blank()) +
  xlab("") + ylab("")
# add a single point
p <- p + geom_point(data=df,aes(lon,lat),colour="blue",size=3)
p
```

Now I want to take each point, compute a 20km by 20km cell centered around the point and then plot the generated cells on the map. How do I then build a grid over the map using such cell sizes? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your data and the code you've used so far. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for help on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
poly.df <- as.data.frame( t( apply(df, 1, 
              function(x) c(                        # for longitude, 
               xmin=x[1]-cos(x[2]*2*pi/360)*20/111.2,  # km/degr varies
               xmax=x[1]+cos(x[2]*2*pi/360)*20/111.2,  # with latitude
               ymin=x[2]-20/111.2,            # but not for lattitude
               ymax=x[2]+20/111.2) ) ) )
```

To be frank, I wasn't sure it's is a simple cos(latitude) adjustment. I checked with the [table in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#The_length_of_a_degree_of_latitude) and it's pretty close:

```
 round( cos(seq(90, 0, by=-15)*2*pi/360)*111.2 , 1)
[1]   0.0  28.8  55.6  78.6  96.3 107.4 111.2
```

But this does get rectangles that look roughly accurate. I'm thinking any off-centered-ness comes from the positioning of the dots.

```
p+geom_rect(data=poly.df, color="red", fill="transparent", 
       aes(xmin=xmin.lon,xmax=xmax.lon, ymin=ymin.lat,ymax=ymax.lat) )
```

To construct a grid:

```
    p+geom_vline(xintercept= seq(-50, -130, by=-1), color="red")+
      geom_hline(yintercept= seq(25,50, by=1), color="red")
```

Comment: thanks. I got the rectangles. Would it be possible to overlay the map by a grid defined by this rectangle/cell size? Then I can probably fill in the selected cells with white to highlight them at scale. Right now it's just solo rectangles on a map.

Comment: I added code to do something like that but it looks entirely ugly to me.

Comment: (Those were one degree gridlines.) I think the projection of the map was such that the gridlines would be correct.